# Play or JPA adding unique constraints to my table

Tags: postgresql, jpa, playframework-2.0

I have a one to many relationship between two models in Playframework 2.1.5. Here's the code :

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
public List<OperationInstance> operations;
```

The database is Postgres 9.2.

A join table is generated with thousands (more than 3000 to be precise) unique constraints:

```
  CREATE TABLE monthly_operationinstance
  (
    monthly_id bigint NOT NULL,
    operations_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_12cd68e7976a4cc59958b9cbaed FOREIGN KEY (operations_id)
        REFERENCES operationinstance (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_1c9bfd55e99b4851ac893c32f86 FOREIGN KEY (monthly_id)
        REFERENCES monthly (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT uk_0003c989137b4707bf686ccce14 UNIQUE (operations_id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_0007f093bce04ff9831e3765a39 UNIQUE (operations_id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_000994722b6c4eecac47b54fa84 UNIQUE (operations_id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_006346e4144f4646a06c79184ec UNIQUE (operations_id),
  ...
```

I've created a new database without any constraints and 2 minutes after starting the application I had 3 new constraints on this table. Any suggestions as to who generates these and why ?

Comment: Those constraint names look strange - they are definitely not generated by Postgres.